# Button press not executing function

Tags: javascript

```
<button type="button" onclick="saveNewData()" style="position: fixed;left: 150px;top: 90px;">Eintragen</button>
<p style="position: fixed; left: 20px">Max.6 Fahrer</p>
<script>
function saveNewData(){
    var Name = $('#Namen :selected').val();
    var Autos = $('#Autos :selected').val();
    var dataString = "decision=saveData+Name+Autos";
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'queries.php',
        data: dataString
        });
}
```

The button didn't call the function when I click it what is wrong?

Comment: what is error on `console`,  Ending`<script>` tag is missing

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Comment: There is no error on console , yes <script> tag was added still dont work

Comment: What method are you using to determine that the function is never called? There is nothing in the function that would give any indication that it was running on the page.

Comment: It is working fine, with your code, you can use `console.log()` inside your function and test it

Comment: No if you put his code in a snippet and test it, it will work perfectly.

Comment: @chsdk try this one inline onclick is not working. http://jsfiddle.net/shishirmorshed/r3h9yc7m/2/

Comment: @ShishirMorshed No this problem is only on jsfiddle, if you put the function  in a script tag inside the HTML editor (not inside the JS editor) [like in **this one**](http://jsfiddle.net/r3h9yc7m/3/) it will work fine, I don't know why but It happens sometimes.

Comment: @chsdk Thanks, got the point.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to close the script tag.

```
<button type="button" onclick="saveNewData()" style="position: fixed;left: 150px;top: 90px;">Eintragen</button>
<script>
function saveNewData(){
alert('Hello');

}
</script>
```

be carefull to close the opened script tag in your code. Now write your own code in that function.